# Python 3 not rendering html on browser

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I run this script on terminal, it outputs the html template. But on browser after serving it using `python3 -m http.server 8000`, it just display the exact script (not rendering). I've installed packages on requirements.txt and interpreter set to Python 3.x, am I missing something here?

**home.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import sys
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

# Get current url
try:
    url = os.environ['SCRIPT_NAME']
except KeyError:
    url = ''

print('Content-type: text/html\n')
env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('templates'))

template = env.get_template('home.html')
print(template.render(url=url))
```

[image]

Comment: You need to open the generated HTML file in the browser, not the Python file.

Comment: @mkrieger1 that's where it lands to. this is the github project https://github.com/pwillworth/dfkreport

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script could work as a [CGI script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface), since it outputs a HTTP header, followed by the HTML content.

`python -m http.server`, by default, does not run CGI scripts for security, [but if you add the `--cgi` switch, it will](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler), provided that the scripts are in the `cgi-bin` directory relative to the directory you start it from.

In other words:

- create a `cgi-bin` directory
- move `home.py` to `cgi-bin/home.py`
- run `python3 -m http.server --cgi 8000`
- navigate to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/cgi-bin/home.py`

When working with CGI scripts, you might want to [enable the (soon-to-be-deprecated) `cgitb` handler too](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cgitb.html).

Anything more intricate than that, and I would recommend looking at the [Flask application framework](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/) instead, though.

Comment: same error. here is the complete source https://github.com/pwillworth/dfkreport. any help will be appreciated

Comment: Ah, so it's a project from somewhere else? Well, why not ask the author how to properly run it?